# iOS 12 enterprise apps crash upon launch

Tags: ios, appcelerator-titanium, ios12

Whenever I run my iOS 12 app, the launch screen shows, and it closes immediately. I've tried creating a new project and run it on my device via USB, it crashes as well. However, if I run it on iOS 12 simulator, everything is working fine.

Below is the details of my build properties and environments:
OS: 10.14 macOS Mojave
Appcelerator Studio: build 5.1.1
Titanium SDK: 7.4.1.GA
iOS SDK Version: 12
Xcode: 10.0

The iPad that I am using has iOS version 12.0.1.

It's not an issue with provisioning profiles, because I've tried to generate new apps id, new profile with a new project, however it still doesn't work on the device.

Appreciate if anyone has any clue what is the cause of the crash, or any clues how to get the log file for the crash.

I tried connecting the iPad to my Mac, sync it through iTunes, and try to find the log file, but I couldn't find a way to do that either.

Comment: From what I can see, this issue is not related to android, why did add that tag? Also please add your code to your question in form of a [mcve], so we can reproduce the crash on our site

Comment: I dont think it is because my code. I tried creating a new project, without changing anything, and run the Hello World example on my device. It crash as well

Comment: Use the Xcode devices window to access the console log of your device and see why your app is failing to launch.

Comment: What does "does not pass CT evaluation, result 0x8008" & "unrecoverable CT signature issue, bailing out" means?

Answer (score 5):

I've found the solution to solve this CT signature issue. All I did is just go to keychain access, change all trust settings to "Use System Defaults" for

1. Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
2. Developer ID Certification Authority
3. iPhone Developer
4. iOS Distribution