# App won't launch after Fastlane build and publish to App Center

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, fastlane

We're using Jenkins and Fastlane to automatically build and publish an app to App Center.

The publishing step is successful and it can be downloaded through App Center, but the app won't launch (it opens and immediately closes).

The builds we have submitted manually have a Provisioning Profile listed in the Release:

[image]

But the Fastlane builds have no value specified here, even though the logs say "All required keys, certificates and provisioning profiles are installed".

[image]

UPDATE: I've done some more digging and checked out the difference between a correct `.xcarchive` and an `.xcarchive` that leads to issues. The problematic one has no signing identity in its `Info.plist` `ApplicationProperties` `SigningIdentity`.

Comment: You can't see the app certificate that is installed on the device. You can set manually the app team ID and provisioning profile with `export_team_id("XXX")` and 
 `export_options({ signingStyle: "manual", provisioningProfiles: {
     "bundle_id" => "provisioning_profile" }}) `, but I don't know if is possible to print the current one on the pipeline. I will follow this question.

Comment: I added those explicit export options but still no luck. I noticed that in App Center, there's a field for Provisioning Profile. The builds we have submitted manually have the correct profile specified here, but the ones created with `gym` have no value. Why would the Provisioning Profile not be included? The logs say "All required keys, certificates and provisioning profiles are installed"

Comment: Are you using an enterprise certificate? Development accounts can’t distribute apps inhouse

Comment: Yes, we’re using enterprise

Comment: Are you able to take the `ipa` that was built from fastlane (directly) and install it on a iOS device and launch it without an issue? I would try that first. If that launches, then the problem is at the App Center side. I am not familiar with App Center, but are you expected to provide certs and profiles for the config of that app, perhaps there is a problem with how that was done?

Comment: I built it using Fastlane locally, uploaded to App Center, and it works as expected. Then I took an .ipa that was built with Fastlane on our Jenkins Server, uploaded it to App Center, and it won't open. I'm thinking it might be a profile issue in the Jenkins Server version of Xcode.

Comment: You are running the same `lane` both locally and in Jenkins? 

Typically, when you are building with Fastlane, the logs will indicate which code signing identity was being used. Have you compared the logs? Is it the same provisioning profile? Can you also add an `archive` step to the Jenkins job to give you the `ipa` so you can download that to your computer and put it in your iOS device?

Comment: I dragged the `.ipa` created by Jenkins into my device, and it won't open. However, if I create the `.ipa` manually from the `.xcarchive` created by Jenkins, that one does open. So the problem lies in going from `.xcarchive` to `.ipa`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this lack of a `SigningIdentity` in the `Info.plist` file of the `.xcarchive` was the root of the problem.

I solved it by going to `Keychain Access` and setting `When using this cerficate:` to `Use System Defaults` on my distribution certificate.

With this in place, the `SigningIdentity` is set properly when creating an archive, and the generated `.ipa` successfully launches on my device.

So it turns out this had nothing to do with Fastlane, just the settings on my Build Server.

I didn't figure this out on my own, this post saved me: [iOS 12 enterprise apps crash upon launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53008981/ios-12-enterprise-apps-crash-upon-launch)